# Refer to forms controls using variable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

*I've seen many threads on this, but I'm pretty much lost.*

For the example below, I have 3 ComboBoxes (cbx_example0, cbx_example1, cbx_example2) located on three TabPages (index 0, 1, 2), respectively. I'd like set the value of the variable myVariable based on the ComboBox on the selected TabPage.
However, I can't seem to figure out how to refer to the ComboBox using a variable. It seems like it should be straightforward, but I guess not. No matter what I do, I get a NullReferenceException.

Function to get TabPage Index number (returns 0 for this example)

```
Function getTabIndex()
    Dim currentTabIndex As Int32 = frm_Main.TabControl1.SelectedIndex
    Return currentTabIndex
End Function
```

Attempt 1 to refer to ComboBox with variable

```
    Dim myVariable As String        
    Dim i As Integer = getTabIndex
    myVariable = frm_Main.Controls("cbx_example" & i).Text
```

Attempt 2 to refer to ComboBox with variable

```
    Dim cbx_example0 As New ComboBox
    Dim i As Integer = getTabIndex()
    Dim name As String = "cbx_example" & i.ToString
    cbx_example = frm_Main.Controls.Item(name)
    myVariable = cbx_example.Text
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you think that your cbo is located on the form, while in reality it is on the `tabpage`. Instead of

```
cbx_example = frm_Main.Controls.Item(name)
```

use (for example)

```
cbx_example = frm_Main.TabPage1.Controls.Item(name)
```

Keep in mind that your combo is probably not on `tab` itself but on the `tabpage`

On another note, I see no need for `getTabIndex()`. And another way to get any control within hierarchy of your form is to use

```
form.Controls.Find(key, searchAllChildren)
```